# What is the name for a auto-changing image gallery that would be situated on a home page with the translucent circles below?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it a lightbox gallery of somesort? I'll try and find an example of what I mean and link it.

I'm not entirely sure how this would be implemented? Would I put it at the bottom of a header element if I wanted it to overlay on top of the transition between the header of the page and the main article text?

Sorry for any lack of knowledge/terminology in advance.

Comment: Its called a carousel, or slider: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=image+carousel&oq=image+carousel&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.1482j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#q=javascript+image+%22carousel+%7C%7C+slider%22

Comment: It’s called _annoying_ …?

Comment: Thanks, the name was all I was after. @CBroe What do you mean?

Comment: http://searchengineland.com/homepage-sliders-are-bad-for-seo-usability-163496

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you are looking for [Slider Evolution](http://codecanyon.net/item/jquery-slider-evolution/270714). I used it for some quick projects and it's really nice and customizable with themes. Explore the [demo page here](http://codecanyon.net/item/jquery-slider-evolution/full_screen_preview/270714)

EDIT: You may as well consider using frameworks like Bootstrap. It has [Carousel Component](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel).

Comment: IMO, there are a lot of open source sliders available which are at par if not better than the paid ones such as the above

Comment: Agree, but it's a fraction of what average programmer Joe earns per hour, so IMO it's almost as good as free ones :)

Comment: But the human mentality is such that it would always give preference to the free ones :)